# Exception in thread "main" io.micronaut.context.exceptions.DependencyInjectionException: Failed to inject value for parameter of class

Tags: java, kotlin, gradle, micronaut, gradle-task

I am not able to inject dependencies through Gradle task

My build.gradle

```
task runDataFeeder(type:JavaExec){
    classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
    main = "example.migrator.RunMigrator"
}
```

runDataFeeder class pointed to RunMigrator class

RunMigrator.kt

```
@Singleton
class Migrator(@Inject val pharmacySeedDataService: PharmacySeedDataService){
    fun migrate(){
        pharmacySeedDataService.createZone()
    }
}

open class RunMigrator {
    companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        fun main(args: Array<String>) {
            ApplicationContext.run().use { applicationContext ->
                val migrator: Migrator = applicationContext.getBean(Migrator::class.java)
                migrator.migrate()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

PharmacySeedDataService.kt contain

```
@Singleton
class PharmacySeedDataService(@Inject private val pharmacyService: PharmacyService, @Inject private val roleService: RoleService) {

    fun createZone() {
       
    }
}
```

And PharmacyService.kt contain

```
@Singleton
class PharmacyService(@Inject val pharmacyRepository: PharmacyRepository){
}
```

Here is PharmacyRepository.kt

```
@Singleton
interface PharmacyRepository {
    fun createZone(zoneName: String, locationName: String): Zone
}
```

But after I ran gradle task, the following exception is thrown:

```
Exception in thread "main" io.micronaut.context.exceptions.DependencyInjectionException: Failed to inject value for parameter [pharmacyRepository] of class: delivery.core.pharmacy.PharmacyService

Message: No bean of type [delivery.core.pharmacy.PharmacyRepository] exists. Make sure the bean is not disabled by bean requirements (enable trace logging for 'io.micronaut.context.condition' to check) and if the bean is enabled then ensure the class is declared a bean and annotation processing is enabled (for Java and Kotlin the 'micronaut-inject-java' dependency should be configured as an annotation processor).
Path Taken: new Migrator([PharmacySeedDataService pharmacySeedDataService]) --> new PharmacySeedDataService([PharmacyService pharmacyService],RoleService roleService) --> new PharmacyService([PharmacyRepository pharmacyRepository])
    at io.micronaut.context.AbstractBeanDefinition.getBeanForConstructorArgument(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:1016)
    at delivery.core.pharmacy.$PharmacyServiceDefinition.build(Unknown Source)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.doCreateBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:1693)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.createAndRegisterSingleton(DefaultBeanContext.java:2402)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.getBeanForDefinition(DefaultBeanContext.java:2084)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.getBeanInternal(DefaultBeanContext.java:2058)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.getBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:1095)
    at io.micronaut.context.AbstractBeanDefinition.getBeanForConstructorArgument(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:1007)
    at delivery.core.pharmacy.$PharmacySeedDataServiceDefinition.build(Unknown Source)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.doCreateBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:1693)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.createAndRegisterSingleton(DefaultBeanContext.java:2402)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.getBeanForDefinition(DefaultBeanContext.java:2084)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.getBeanInternal(DefaultBeanContext.java:2058)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.getBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:1095)
    at io.micronaut.context.AbstractBeanDefinition.getBeanForConstructorArgument(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:1007)
    at delivery.core.$MigratorDefinition.build(Unknown Source)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.doCreateBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:1693)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.createAndRegisterSingleton(DefaultBeanContext.java:2402)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.getBeanForDefinition(DefaultBeanContext.java:2084)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.getBeanInternal(DefaultBeanContext.java:2058)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.getBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:623)
    at delivery.core.RunMigrator$Companion.main(RunMigrator.kt:20)
    at delivery.core.RunMigrator.main(RunMigrator.kt)
Caused by: io.micronaut.context.exceptions.NoSuchBeanException: No bean of type [delivery.core.pharmacy.PharmacyRepository] exists. Make sure the bean is not disabled by bean requirements (enable trace logging for 'io.micronaut.context.condition' to check) and if the bean is enabled then ensure the class is declared a bean and annotation processing is enabled (for Java and Kotlin the 'micronaut-inject-java' dependency should be configured as an annotation processor).
Caused by: io.micronaut.context.exceptions.NoSuchBeanException: No bean of type [delivery.core.pharmacy.PharmacyRepository] exists. Make sure the bean is not disabled by bean requirements (enable trace logging for 'io.micronaut.context.condition' to check) and if the bean is enabled then ensure the class is declared a bean and annotation processing is enabled (for Java and Kotlin the 'micronaut-inject-java' dependency should be configured as an annotation processor).
```

Comment: Do you have a full stack trace of the exception? Also post the DataServiceRepository code? Or confirm that it has an @Repository annotation

Comment: @k.wahome edited my post, please check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an [@Repository](https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-data/latest/api/io/micronaut/data/annotation/Repository.html) annotation to designate that `PharmacyRepository` is a type of a data repository that's then registered as a bean at runtime. If the type is an interface or abstract class this annotation will attempt to automatically provide implementations at compilation time.

You can also extend the [CrudRepository](https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-data/latest/api/io/micronaut/data/repository/CrudRepository.html) interface to enable automatic generation of CRUD (Create, Read, Update, Delete) operations.

For instance:

```
import io.micronaut.data.annotation.*
import io.micronaut.data.model.*
import io.micronaut.data.repository.CrudRepository

@Repository
interface PharmacyRepository extends CrudRepository<YOUR ENTITY HERE, YOUR ENTITY ID HERE> {
}
```

If you don’t want to expose all CRUD operation, for example you only allow entities to be created/updated instead of extending `CrudRepository` you can extend [GenericRepository](https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-data/latest/api/io/micronaut/data/repository/GenericRepository.html).

Another option is to use a custom implementation of the `PharmacyRepository` to which you then add the `@Repository` annotation.

```
import io.micronaut.data.annotation.*

interface PharmacyRepository {
    fun createZone(zoneName: String, locationName: String): Zone
}

...

@Repository
class PharmacyRepositoryImpl implements PharmacyRepository {
    // implement declared methods of the interface here
}
```

See 2.4 Repository Access of [Micronaut Guides - Access a database with JPA and Hibernate](https://guides.micronaut.io/micronaut-data-access-jpa-hibernate/guide/index.html)

Comment: Thanks, man!  I used the second option to solved my problem.